# Mongoid virtual attributes in to_json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I'm trying to get some virtual (non-persisted) attributes to show up in the JSON representation of some Mongoid models, but can't seem to get it to work:

```
class MyModel
  include Mongoid::Document

  def virtual_attribute
    @my_attribute || false
  end

  def virtual_attribute=(value)
    @my_attribute=value
  end
end

class MyController
  def myaction
    false_values=MyModel.where( whatever )
    true_values=MyModel.where( something_else ).map{ |model| model.virtual_attribute=true }
    @val['my_models']=false_values+true_values
    render json: @val.to_json( :include => {:my_models => {:methods => %w(virtual_attribute)}} )
  end
end
```

`virtual_attribute` doesn't appear in the json.  What am I doing wrong?

*Edit* - ok, so I guess my actual problem is that I can't figure out how to invoke the `virtual_attribute` method on each of an array of objects that is nested in the root object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`to_json` passes the options directly to the array and the objects. `:include` is only a Mongoid thing:

```
render json: @val.to_json(methods: :virtual_attribute)
```

Comment: But that assumes that I'm invoking `to_json` on the array directly, right?  Everything seems to indicate that it invokes `virtual_attribute` on, in my case, `@val` and not `@val['my_models']` - am I just tragically mistaken?

Comment: Well, it depends. As you did not specify what `@val.class` is, I assumed that it's a `Hash` and `Hash` will just pass the options on to `@val['my_models']` which in turn passes the options to your models.

Comment: `@val` is actually a Mongoid model - I didn't realize `methods` normally applied to all sub-objects.  In any case, my experiments with this seem to have failed...

Comment: I just tested it with a Mongoid model and it works the same way, because `@val['my_models']` is not a relation. Only relations need the `:include`.

Comment: There must be something really weird that I don't understand going on then, because it doesn't include that attribute in the json for me...  Let me try your solution from my other question.