# Ruby/Mongoid decorate record with new attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid

I'm trying to figure out how to decorate a specific Mongoid record with an attribute so that `to_json` comes back with that attribute included (please do not tell me to pass specific arguments to `to_json` - this is doubly nested and that won't work here).  Is there any way to do this?  All I can come up with is

```
my_record[:my_special_attribute]='foo'
```

which of course doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two versions that might work for you:

**Overwrite `to_json`:**

```
require 'mongoid'
Mongoid.load!("mongoid.yml", :development)

class MyClass
  include Mongoid::Document

  def to_json(options = {})
    json = JSON.parse(super)
    json['my_special_attribute'] = 'whatever you want'
    json.to_json
  end
end

p MyClass.new.to_json # => "{\"_id\":\"5155899ee44f7ba6e7000001\",\"my_special_attribute\":\"whatever you want\"}"
```

**Pass an argument to `to_json` (sorry - for the sake of completeness):**

```
require 'mongoid'
Mongoid.load!("mongoid.yml", :development)

class MyClass
  include Mongoid::Document

  def not_a_field
    "whatever you want"
  end
end

p MyClass.new.to_json(methods: :not_a_field) # => "{\"_id\":\"51558b67e44f7bddb7000001\",\"my_special_attribute\":\"whatever you want\"}"
```

You can even pass this option to nested records (I guess that's what you mean by doubly nested):

```
my_record.to_json(include: {other_class: {methods: :special_field}})
```

You can also add this method to one specific record (= instance):

```
my_object = MyClass.new

def my_object.not_a_field
  "whatever you want"
end 
p my_object.to_json(methods: :not_a_field) # => "{\"_id\":\"51558cc8e44f7bd1f6000001\",\"not_a_field\":\"whatever you want\"}"
```

Comment: Just saw your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15692872/mongoid-virtual-attributes-in-to-json). Try my answer there first.

Comment: Overwriting `to_json` didn't work, but overwriting `as_json` seems to do the trick...